# C# Collection Group Related Elements

Tags: c#, collections

I have a collection of points, I am attempting to write a function which groups all related points.

For example, related in this case means that an item contains the other:

```
int[] points = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 2, 13, 14, 15, 32, 10, 237, 22, 46, 97}
getDirectRelatives(2) = {2, 2, 32, 237, 22}
```

This works for returning all directly related elements.  But I would like to group the indirectly related elements.  Since 3 and 7 have indirect relations to 2, I want all of their direct relations too:

```
getAllRelatives(2) = {2, 2, 32, 237, 22, 3, 13, 32, 7, 97}
```

Any suggestions?

**Update:** Here's my implementation to make it more clear. This works but I'd like to know if it's the correct approach

```
public void getAllRelatives()
{
int groupIndex = 1;
List<int> groupCollection = new List<int>();
bool flag = false;
int[] marked = null;
string currentOuter = null;
string currentInner = null;
List<int> current = new List<int>();
int[] points = {2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 2, 13, 14, 15, 32, 10, 237, 22, 46, 97};

//marked contains integers which identify which group an element belongs to
for (x = 0; x <= marked.Count - 1; x++) {
    marked(x) = 0;
}

//Two loops.  The first iterates over the target point, the second iterates over each sub point
//Once both loops are complete, groupCollection should contain the indexes for
//all related integers

//outerloop
for (i = 0; i <= points.Count - 1; i++) {
    current.Clear();
    currentOuter = points(i).ToString;
    current.Add(i); //used to hold matches for current loop

    //inner loop, targetpoint + 1 to end
    for (x = i + 1; x <= points.Count - 1; x++) {
        currentInner = points(x).ToString;

        if (currentInner.Contains(currentOuter)) {
            current.Add(x);
        }
    }

    //if this is the first iteration, flag as true, forces current items to marked
    if (marked(0) == 0) {
        flag = true;
    }

    //check if any current points are marked and flag if any of the elements are already in a group, add each found group to group collection
    for (x = 0; x <= current.Count - 1; x++) {
        if (!(marked(current(x)) == 0)) {
            flag = true;
            groupCollection.Add(marked(current(x)));
        }
    }

    if (flag == true) {
        groupCollection.Add(groupIndex); //all relatives end up here
    }

    for (x = 0; x <= current.Count - 1; x++) {
        marked(current(x)) = groupIndex;
    }
    groupIndex += 1;
    flag = false;


}
```

}

Comment: First find all that contain 2s. Find all other numbers contained in those, then research finding the others indirectly related. Is that too obvious? Do you intend to keep applying this to each new set?

Comment: Just realized you're not using strings, you'll need to for a more logical (non-mathematical) way of searching like the one I'm suggesting.

Comment: I don't think I understand what you mean by _indirectly related_.  Why is _22_ not included in your second array?  Why are _13_, _43_, and _97_ included in your second array?

Comment: @steaks: OP means 32 makes 3 a valid search term, now find numbers with 3. Not sure why some fell off though. It looks like it should be there where the third 2 is. Likely a typo.

Comment: @C.Lang Do you mean _32_?  If so, I understand why _3_ is _indirectly related_ to _2_.  But I still don't see why _13_ for example is _indirectly related_ to 2.

Comment: @C.Lang Still, why is _13_ _indirectly related_ to _2_?

Comment: @steaks: Sorry, another edit. I'm guessing that three makes a relationship to 2 in that now all numbers with 3, like 13, are "indirectly" related. Same goes for the seven.

Comment: @C.Lang But not _9_ even though _97_ contains a _9_.  I think the OP needs to fix up his examples and make his specifications clear.

Comment: @steaks: That's why I asked in my first comment if OP wanted to continually re-apply this. When does it end?? I reluctantly assume it's only numbers with only one level indirectness :).

Comment: @C.Lang: The actual implementation is being applied to a list of x,y points.  I'm trying to group all of the points which share a boundary.  I simplified a bit with my example since the function should be pretty much the same with either data set.

Answer (score 0):

convert `int[] points` to `Dictionary<int, string[]> pointTokens`

e.g.

```
pointTokens.Add(237, new string[]{"2", "3", "7"})
```

Then use `pointTokens` for finding relationships (how ever arbitary)

```
foreach(int point in pointTokens.Keys)
{
  string[] tokens = pointTokens[point]

  if(someInt.Equals(point))
  {
    // do something
  }

  if(tokens.Contains(someInt.ToString())
  {
     // do something
  }

  // etc ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably best solved as a graph theory question. You need to figure out how to create an appropriate graph to represent your data, and then traverse it for your answers.

Comment: Yes, use a graph for parsing a large data set. Overkill for small sets